# clj-ssh / JSch unable to load library 'c' on Windows

Tags: java, ssh, clojure, jna, jsch

I've added clj-ssh as a dependency to a Leiningen project, and I can `(use 'clj-ssh.ssh)` but calling `(ssh-agent {})` gives the error

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError Unable to load library 'c': The specified module cannot be found.
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadNativeLibrary
...
at org.jcraft.jsch.agentproxy.usocket.JNAUSocketFactory$CLibrary.(clinit)
...
```

Anyone know why this is? I'm thinking it could be to do with Windows not coming with a C standard library, in which case could installing e.g. cygwin help?

Comment: `libc` is called `msvcrt` on windows (more or less).  However, I'd suggest checking your `clj-ssh` documentation to see whether they support windows.  You can sometimes get by substituting, `msvcrt` for `c`, but sockets on windows don't behave the same as on other platforms, so you'd need some work beyond a simple library substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some digging in the source it seems that clj-ssh attempts to use the system ssh-agent by default (which seems like strange behaviour if it isn't windows compatible). This makes `clj-ssh.cli` unusable but `clj-ssh.ssh` is fine with the fix

```
(ssh-agent {:use-system-ssh-agent false})
```

If you do want to use a system ssh-agent, the readme for clj-ssh and ymnk below mention PuTTY's pageant, I couldn't find any info on setting this up but it should be doable with cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing cygwin and add something like:

```
-Djava.library.path=...path to lib dir ...
```

if it doesn't find the library on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [jsch-agent-proxy](https://github.com/ymnk/jsch-agent-proxy), which has been used in clj-ssh.

I think it will not work for cygwin's ssh-agent, because JNA does not provide
the native library for it.  How about trying Putty's Pageant?  If you need to use cygwin's ssh-agent and "nc" command exits on your cygwin environment, how about using [NCUSocketFactory](https://github.com/ymnk/jsch-agent-proxy/blob/master/jsch-agent-proxy-usocket-nc/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/agentproxy/usocket/NCUSocketFactory.java)?  I'm not so familiar with clj-ssh, but it will be possible to use NCUSocketFactroy instead of JNAUSocketFactory, according to [agent.clj](https://github.com/hugoduncan/clj-ssh/blob/develop/src/clj_ssh/agent.clj).

**UPDATE:**
I have confirmed that I can successfully run clj-ssh with
ssh-agent on my Cygwin environment by applying the following commit,

[GitHub clj-ssh commit:f1109e2c0dfa25c9db563b2f64d2b7dcb4653adf](https://github.com/ymnk/clj-ssh/commit/f1109e2c0dfa25c9db563b2f64d2b7dcb4653adf)

Comment: You *might* be able to drop in `cygwin1.dll` (or whatever it's called) in place of the `libc` load, since cygwin offers API compatibility on windows.  To avoid requiring changes to the Java code, you might try making a copy of `cygwin1.dll` called `c.dll` and put it somewhere in `PATH` so JNA can find it.  You'd basically be presenting the cygwin dll as if it were `libc`.

Comment: I had tried to use JNA with cywgin, but I could not find how to do that.  It is a good news for me if it is possible.

Comment: Well, *possible* might be a far cry from *feasible*.  It might be as easy as making a copy of `cygwin1.dll` named `c.dll`, but it might be much, much more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I didn't realise that clj-ssh was looking for an external ssh-agent so this prompted me to figure out the fix. Incidentally, the readme also mentions pageant in passing but I can't find any info on setting this up.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this if the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is set.  Clearing this environment variable before starting the jvm might solve the issue.

When `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is not set, clj-ssh should automatically use pageant if it is running.

Looks like the best solution would be to support NCUSocketFactory as per ymnk's commit, and add documentation about cygwin's ssh-agent.  Happy to take a pull request for that.